# TeXstudio: open file at line number n

Tags: files, scripting, editors, latex, texstudio

I am creating a script to produce some `.tex` files with a lot of lines (a kind of automatic sample).

The script finishes with `texstudio /home/$USER/foo.tex` where `foo.tex` is the file created before.

My question is: is it possible to open the file with `texstudio` with the cursor at line N, that is, I would like to run the script to open the file and start typing right now, exactly at the right line.

Thanks for a while. Below is the script.

---

```
file=/home/$USER/fastex-temp.tex
exec 3>&1 # save file descriptor to stdout
exec > "$file" # redirect output to file
printf '\\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}\n'
printf '\\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,amsmath}\n'
printf '\\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}\n'
printf '\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\n'
printf ' ' >&3 # output to normal stdout instead of file
printf '\\begin{document}\n'
printf ' ' >&3
printf '\\end{document}\n'
exec >&3  # restore stdout
exec 3>&- # close / discard temporary fd

texstudio "$file"
```

Comment: The usual convention for editors is `$EDITOR +42 foo.tex` to open `foo.tex` at line 42. I don't know if TeXstudio follows it.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for your help. I will update my script. I confess that I don't know some commands, but it looks like much more organized than mine. Just one question: `printf ' ' >&3` will produce an empty line? This is what I wish.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did you reply to the wrong post? `printf ' '` prints a space. Your script would be more readable with a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) (search on this site for examples).

Comment: @Gilles, I wrote based on your comment `# output to normal stdout instead of file`. So, this line will print an empty space on a single line of the file or not?

Comment: That wasn't me, that was @jw013. jw013: you shouldn't edit code in questions like this. Your answer would have been a good place to put an improved script.

Comment: Sorry. For me, your name (Gilles) appears as the editor  of my questions, around 1 hour ago.Any way, thanks for everybody.

Comment: @Sigur You can click on the date link to see the edit history.

Comment: Oh, I see. There are more than one edits. Now I understand. Well, I'm getting some errors with the last line `find . -name  "$file*" | grep -vP '.tex$|.pdf$' | while read -r i; do rm $i; done`. Since that I am finding all file with the same name I choose to remove the extension `.tex` on `file` variable. But I don't know if I can write something like this `exec "$file.tex"` or `exec "$file".tex`. But I decided to use the full file name for the `find` command. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
texstudio --line "$lineno" "$file"
```

?

This is [documented in the TeXstudio manual](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION38).

Comment: Thanks so much. It works! I didn't know about this nice manual. Thanks!